# gdb: cannot set breakpoint : "no symbol table is loaded. use the "file" command."

Tags: gcc, gdb

while using gdb I cannot set any breakpoint even if I use the `file` command:

```
   (gdb) file crab_spectrum
    Load new symbol table from "crab_spectrum"? (y or n) y
    Reading symbols from crab_spectrum...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
    (gdb) b file crab_spectrum.c:45
    No source file named file crab_spectrum.c.
    Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
    Breakpoint 3 (file crab_spectrum.c:45) pending.
```

When I then run the code, it doesn't stop at the breakpoint. I am compiling with the following Makefile:

```
CC =  gcc
LD = gcc
LIBGSL = -L/home/martin/gsl/gsl-2.4/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
CFLAGSRELEASE = -O -Wall -I/home/dirsonlu/gsl/gsl-2.4/include
LFLAGSRELEASE = -lm -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib $(LIBGSL)
CFLAGSDEBUG = -g -p  -Wall
LFLAGSDEBUG = -lm 
CFLAGSDEBUG = -g -p  -Wall -W    # -DDEBUG_OUTPUT
LFLAGSDEBUG =  -lm -p -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib $(LIBGSL) 

LIBS= -L/home/dupont/folder/soft/pgplot -lm -lcpgplot /home/dupont/folder/soft/pgplot/libpgplot.a  -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11

CFLAGS = $(CFLAGSRELEASE)
LFLAGS = $(LFLAGSRELEASE)

OBJECTS = \
    crab_spectrum.o initialize.o nel.o sync.o table_fonction.o table_bessel.o ic_lud.o calc_crab_lud.o create_table.o
    #crab_spectrum.o initialize.o nel.o sync.o  ic.o calc_crab_dens.o create_table.o




FIT_IT_OBJECTS = \
    fit_it.o create_table.o initialize.o nel.o sync.o table_bessel.o

FIT_IT_DATA_OBJECTS = \
    fit_it_data.o create_table.o initialize.o nel.o sync.o table_bessel.o   calc_crab_dens.o  ic.o 

FIT_IT_SCALE_OBJECTS = \
    fit_it_scale.o create_table.o initialize.o nel.o sync.o table_bessel.o   calc_crab_manu.o  ic_manu.o 

PRG = crab_spectrum 
crab_spectrum: $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(OBJECTS) $(LFLAGS) -o $(PRG)


clean:
    rm -f *.o $(PRG) $(FIT_IT)
```

Does someone has any idea what I could do?

Answer (score 0):

> Does someone has any idea what I could do?

What is the *actual* command used to compile? How did you invoke `make`?

Chances are, `rm *.o; make` produces something like:

```
gcc -O -Wall ...
```

in which case you want to change this:

```
CFLAGS = $(CFLAGSRELEASE)
LFLAGS = $(LFLAGSRELEASE)
```

to this:

```
CFLAGS = $(CFLAGSDEBUG)
LFLAGS = $(LFLAGSDEBUG)
```

and rebuild again.

Comment: I use "make file.exec"

Comment: @ludmi That's mostly useless piece of info. What GCC command does that run?

Comment: I know but I didn't understand the question then. I edit the all Makefile.